# Why does Unity does not import materials of .DAE file?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collada, sketchup

I'm trying to upload a DAE file (Exported from SketchUp) into Unity3D.

It imports the meshes, but all of them are grey. I guess it imports materials too, but all materials become grey or something. Here are the pictures of what I mean :

SketchUp :
[image]

Unity :
[image]

How can I import the materials with colors (or textures) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [Mesh Import Settings](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/FBXImporter-Model.html) on the model you imported in Unity3D you'll see there is an option to generate the materials for you based on what is in the mesh file.

See [this page](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Mesh.html) on the official documentation around importing models and their materials and assigning the textures to the materials.

Comment: Thanks ! I guess I need to add textures manually.

Comment: But I wish there were an automatic way. Since the texture names and material names are the same..

Comment: If you follow the guidelines as stipulated in the above Unity docs, Unity should be able to find the textures and materials for you.

Comment: As Jeff Kesselman answered in Unity's forum:
> i find my collada imports fine IF I import the textures first.